# Laravel How to prevent a user from viewing other user's data

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, restful-authentication

I'm new to Laravel and I'm doing an app on L5.4.

I have a view page, like, applicant/list/{job_id} where job_id is a job owned by the currently logged in user but the problem is this very user can view that data for any job(owned by anyone) by just changing the job_id. So, a user can view all of applicant/list/11, applicant/list/12, applicant/list/13, no matter who these job_ids belong to.

Does Laravel provide inbuilt function? What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does have this functionality builtin, check out the documentation on [Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization).

You'll probably be particularly interested in how [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#creating-policies) work. They are quite flexible, usable through [Controllers, Models, Middleware, etc.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#creating-policies) to only allow the owner of the job to see the data:

```
public function view(User $user, Job $job)
{
    return $user->id === $job->user_id;
}
```

Then you can use the policy in a controller:

```
$this->authorize('view', $job);
```

Or view:

```
@can('view', $job)
    {{-- User can view the job --}}
@endcan
```

Or any other class:

```
if ($user->can('view', $job)) {
    // User can view the job
}
```